# Is it a bug for zsh to run a quarantined script?

Tags: zsh, textedit, security

Update: I am not going to delete the question although it is useless.  The answer is, Yes, it would be a bug, but zsh doesn’t do that.  I screwed up writing the details.  A quarantined script can be edited with `vi` in zsh but it cannot be executed. Since a more detailed answer was provided (even though we allegedly cannot answer a closed question), I’ll leave it up for reference.

Background:

I have several zsh scripts in ~/bin and I have often edited them with TextEdit.

Today, however, every time I edit one with TextEdit and save it, TextEdit can no longer open it again—would claim it was damaged and should be moved to the trash.

`od -xc` showed **no** non-ASCII characters.

`ls -lae@t` showed that it had a quarantine tag!

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine` bin said "xattr: bin/Mission: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine" and removed all the `xattr`s¹ and then TextEdit was able to open it.

Note that someone else had the [opposite behavior](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391765/how-to-stop-textedit-app-from-adding-extended-attributes/391859): TextEdit could still open it, but they could no longer execute the file.

For TextEdit to suddenly start doing this when nothing has been updated for over a week (except iMovie) is clearly a bug.  **But is it a bug for zsh to still execute a quarantined script?**  This is not an opinion question.  Apple probably has documentation somewhere describing what should happen.  If they don't, and someone **knows** they don't, then that is the answer.  If they do, what that documentation (that I haven't seen) says is the answer.

When one person is able to run a quarantined script, and another is not, there is a bug on one side or another.

¹including the encoding, not that it matters for this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer pertains to macOS Monterey 12.0.1.

It is not a bug for zsh to execute a quarantined script. Below explains why I believe this to be true.

The issues raised in the OP's question are to do with the content of the `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute and not necesarily to the existence of the attribute itself.

The TextEdit application is adding a `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute when saving edited script files. My example script file named `bar` is shown below.

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo "hi there"
```

The content of this `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute is given below.

```
0086;6198914d;TextEdit;
```

The article [Quarantine and the quarantine flag](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/10/29/quarantine-and-the-quarantine-flag/) refers to the first for characters (`0086`) as the quarantine value in hexadecimal. The `6198914d` character string is the time at which the extended attribute was attached, in hexadecimal.  After some testing, I determined the script will not execute (from the default zsh) with an `zsh: operation not permitted: bar` message when the `0x0004` bit is set. Otherwise, the script will execute. Since the `0x0004` bit is set in the quarantine value of `0x0086`, the script is prevented from executing.

When using Safari to download a file from the internet, a `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute is attached to the file. Example content of this `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute is given below.

```
0083;61991274;Safari;773A774E-C8E8-41A4-8EC3-AF0E00656893
```

Here, the `0x0004` bit is not set in the quarantine value of `0x0083`. This `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute will not prevent a script from executing.

### Regarding the Use of TextEdit

You can open the script in the TextEdit application, if any of the `0xFF40` bits are set. Otherwise, you get the following popup, if the `0x0004` bit is set.

[image: damaged]

Any other combination results in the following popup.

[image: developer]

Of course, I did not try every 65536 possible integers for the quarantine value. Therefore, there may exist exceptions to what I posted above.