# Why does globbing not work on X* or x*?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

Due to a [bug in Monterey](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431040/is-it-a-bug-for-zsh-to-run-a-quarantined-script), TextEdit quarantines any file it changes.  `xattr` can fix it, and since I didn't know where such might be, I tried to do `xattr -rc ~`

But something in ~/Library prevents that from completing¹, so I tried
xattr -rc {A..K}* {M..Z}* {a..z}*
That failed with the complaint that `x*` doesn't exist—but it does!  (I created an empty file for every letter of the alphabet to avoid this error.)

When I fix that, it complained about `X*` but it has no problem globbing a * after any other letter:

```
user@mac ~ % xattr -rc {A..K}* {M..Z}* {a..w}* {y,z}
zsh: no matches found: X*
user@mac ~ % xattr -rc {A..K}* {M..W}* {Y,Z}* {a..w}* {y,z}
xattr: No such file: Bible/002_John_1,1-18,nl,HTB.txt
```

(Second error is because of a bad symlink)

**What is special about `X*` that disables globbing?**

Update: I am aware of the pros and cons about `xattr -rc`.  That's not the question.  The same effect is seen with ls -d instead.

¹Probably a looping circle of symlinks.  I've seen that in some frameworks in /System/Library

Comment: I cannot replicate this error. But why not just use `[A-KM-Za-z]*` or even `[^L]*`?

Comment: TextEdit seems to add a quarantine xattr to .txt files, but not .rtf files. But frankly, I'd use any other text editor in preference for scripting.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I could use a regex in the same place as the {} syntax.  That will come in handy; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not a good idea to remove all attributes from all files in your home folder, as you're trying to do here.

There's nothing special about "X*" that disables globbing. As you indicate you have created empty files for other letters, you can simply create one for X as well if this is the method you insist on using. In the Terminal run:

```
touch ~/Xisafile
```

Note that in ordinary macOS setups, the file system is non-case sensitive. I.e. "x" and "X" in a file name is considered the same. However when you run `xattr` like you have done, you need to take case into account.

Note: I don't think it has actually been established that anything you're experiencing here is in fact due to bugs in Monterey. I think that's jumping to conclusions.

Comment: I didn't ask whether it is a good idea.  And I specifically said the X and x do exist.  I  also tried creating xx, but it didn't find that either.  And the _only_ mention of a bug links to the description of the bug that was the reason for this experiment.  This globbing oddity may or may not be a bug, hence the question.  A question is not a conclusion.  As for case sensitivity, almost everything in Terminal is case sensitive.

Comment: Actually, X and x did NOT both exist.  I am so accustomed to case sensitivity in the shell that I sometimes forget the file system disagrees.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're complaining about and why I get all the downvotes.. as you mention, this is the correct answer - you simply needed to have both a file starting with "X" and with "x" - and you did not have those - even though you might have thought you had. So the answer works. You might not have asked whether or not it is a good idea, but I link to comment on that, so that newcomers to Macs don't rush into doing something before realizing that it might be a bad idea. Experienced users can always disregard that advice.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is hinted at by jksoegaard: case insensitivity.

For every letter except X, there is at least one file or directory that starts with upper case and at least one that starts with lower case.  If **X** exists, `touch x` changes it without creating **X**.  So one was always missing.

Comment: Hinted at the answer? - I gave the answer. I don't know why you answer your own question with essentially the same answer I gave.