# How to make Chinese pinyin keyboard work in vim?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, input-source, vi

When I am using a Chinese keyboard as input source, I cannot navigate around vim using regular keys.

I would like to leave the Chinese keyboard selected, but still be able to use vim as normal when I am not in insert mode.

When in Insert mode, any typing should type Chinese, but when not in a typing mode keys should have their normal vim functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow keys still work, but other than that, you'd have to switch keyboards to navigate or turn on insert/replace/delete functions, then switch back.  Perhaps use Cmd-dot to toggle back and forth.

If you have a numeric keypad, you could program some of those keys with different navigation outputs.  Or function keys.

I use mostly TextEdit.  I’ll get some downvotes for having the audacity to suggest it’s not completely useless.  Other editors are available that do a lot more.  But there’s some value in choosing a simpler product that does everything you need over one that can do a lot of things you don’t need.  Can’t recommend TextEdit for Monterey, though—Apple is still working on a [serious bug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/431518/65467).